# Issue with win cmd finding folders

Tags: windows

I am having an issue with the windows cmd line. When I *cd* into my Users dir my user folder shows as there but I cannot *cd* into. The path `cd\Users\gmenfan83\` is my desired location. However, when I am in the *Users* dir and `cd\Users\gmenfan83 \` I get a "The path is not found or specified" . I am more of a nix user but if the folder shows in the directory tree shouldn't I be able to cd into it? Thank you

Comment: Then you're clearly not typing it correctly, or you're not correctly navigating the folder structure. It's difficult to say which, because we don't know what the current directory is when you try to CD or where specifically you are trying to CD into. What **specifically** do you see as the command prompt? And from that same prompt, what **specifically** are you typing? I use the command prompt regularly to do things quickly, and I assure you that CD works fine when used properly.

Comment: I updated the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear (even after your edit) what specifically you're doing, but this should get you started.

If you're currently in `C:\users`, and you want to change into the `C:\Users\gmenfan83` folder, all you need is `cd gmenfan83`. If you're in `C:\`, all you need is `cd users\gmenfan83`.

Relative paths also work in Windows cmd.exe just as they do under *nix. To change from `C:\users\gmenfan83\test` to `C:\users\gmenfan83\temp`, you can use `cd ..\temp`, or specify `cd \users\gmenfan83\temp`.

Comment: Sorry for the clarity of my question. I am doing exactly as you mentioned and still get the same output.

Comment: Then you're NOT doing exactly what I described. I can assure you with absolute certainty that it works precisely as I've described. It worked the same exact way two decades ago in MS-DOS, and with the exception of spaces in paths and filenames (and the need to quote them), nothing has changed in that regard.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to use `cd/Users/gmenfan83` while you have already used `cd/Users`? In that case you will not be able to find the file since you are already in the Users folder. Typing `cd \Users\gmenfan83` right after opening cmd with C drive path should get you there.